# Butterscotch Pie setting

Tags: pie, filling

I am using a recipe taken from this [Recipe for Butterscotch Pie](https://www.eazypeazymealz.com/no-bake-butterscotch-pie/) recipe. I will post a picture below as well.

The main ingredients for the pie are 2 3.4 ounce instant butterscotch pudding mixes with 12 ounces of cool whip and 2 cups of milk. After combining the ingredients, and half of the cool whip, my butterscotch filling turns into a runny mess rather than a fluffy filling. Even after putting in the fridge for a couple of days, it does not set at all.

I was wondering how I can modify this in order to get the filling to a fluffy consistency.

Ingredients:

> - 1 2/3 cups Graham Cracker Crumbs
> - 1/4 Cup Sugar
> - 6 Tablespoons butter melted
> - 2 3.4 Ounce Boxes Instant Butterscotch Pudding Mix
> - 2 Cups Cold Milk
> - 12 Ounces Cool Whip Butterscotch Sundae Topping Optional
> - 1/4 Cup Chopped Pecans optional